# Javascript client page dont catch Python Flask emit signal

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask, signals

in my project on event "CONNECT" i emit many signals:

```
@sock.on( "connect" )
def connectHandler():
    logger.info("User logged")

    for k, v in mapMsg: #mapMsg is a map of msg
        msg = v.getValuesToString()  #msg is a string
        sock.emit( 'ActionPending', {'data': msg}, namespace="/test" )
```

in index.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block scripts %}
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js" integrity="sha256-yr4fRk/GU1ehYJPAs8P4JlTgu0Hdsp4ZKrx8bDEDC3I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            namespace = '/test'
            var socket = io(namespace);

            socket.on('connect', function() {
                console.log('CONNECT EVENT'); //<-- I READ THIS ON CONSOLE!
            });

        var d=0;
        socket.on('ActionPending', function(msg) {
            console.log("Sono qui con msg: "+msg)  //<--this i dont view!
           if (d > 3 ){
                $('#log4').empty()
               d=0;
           }
           $('#log4').append('<br>' + $('<div/>').text('ActionPending: ' + msg.data).html());
           d++;
            //if (cb)
                //cb();
        });

    <dt><h3>ActionPending:</h3></dt>
    <dd><div id="log4"></div></dd>
```

I view always CONNECT EVENT on connect event. But i dont view msg object.
Some Tips?
thanks
Regards

Comment: It looks like your 'ready' function doesn't have closing braces?

The issue could be that you are defining socket when the page is ready but the socket.on event handler outside of the ready function and before socket is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Besides missing a few semi-colons and var declarations, you're missing closing brackets for your document.ready function and a closing script tag.

The issue that you're having is because the variable 'socket' is in the namespace of the anonymous function being called on document.ready.

The 'ActionPending' socket event is defined outside of the document.ready function. If you adjust the code so that the 'ActionPending' event is also within the document.ready function, your code should work as intended

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block scripts %}
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js" integrity="sha256-yr4fRk/GU1ehYJPAs8P4JlTgu0Hdsp4ZKrx8bDEDC3I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var namespace = '/test';
        var socket = io(namespace);

        socket.on('connect', function() {
            console.log('CONNECT EVENT'); //<-- I READ THIS ON CONSOLE!
        });

        var d=0;
        socket.on('ActionPending', function(msg) {
            console.log("Sono qui con msg: "+msg);  //<--this i dont view!
            if (d > 3 ){
                $('#log4').empty();
                d=0;
            }
            $('#log4').append('<br>' + $('<div/>').text('ActionPending: ' + msg.data).html());
            d++;
            //if (cb)
                //cb();
        });
    });
    </script>
    <dt><h3>ActionPending:</h3></dt>
    <dd><div id="log4"></div></dd>
```